# HP Zbook 15 brightness adjustment issue after an update

Tags: nvidia

I am using HP ZBook15. i7, 4800MQ processor with 16GB RAM and NVIDIA Quadro 2100M.
I am facing a problem, when I update the the driver for

*HP Hotkey Support 5.0.27.1 (11 Jun 2014)*

The function keys <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> for brightness adjustment does not works and not even from control panel options.

Please help me to advise how to resolve this issues as I am unable to understand the issue. Even HP guys are not helping on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? As far as I know HP does not provide Linux drivers (at least for their notebooks) so I'd guess that you are actually having problems with Windows. If not, please add details about your Ubuntu installation.